# How to solve exception with inbound-channel-adapter poller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Сould not find an answer.
Spring version 5.0.6.
My config:

```
<int:channel id="data"/>

<int:inbound-channel-adapter 
    id="dataAdapter"                                                                    
    channel="data"                                    
    auto-startup="false"
    ref="dataGetter"
    method="myMessageSource">
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="10"/>
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>
<beans:bean
    class="org.endpoints.DataGetter"
    id="dataGetter"/>
```

Throw exception:

```
Configuration problem: A <poller> must have one and only one trigger configuration.
```

If no poller:

```
No poller has been defined for channel-adapter 'dataAdapter', and no default poller is available within the context.
```

How to properly setup the poller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your config:

```
<int:poller max-messages-per-poll="10"/>
```

You don't meet the condition to have or `fixed-delay`, or `fixed-rate`, or `cron`, or just `trigger` reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#endpoint-namespace

Comment: Thanx! IDE somehow does not show some poller attributes.